# YouTube API v3 request more items with nextPageToken (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get more than 50 results using nextPageToken. I need to collect all the videos from a playlist or a channel and then pick random videos from the obtained list. The problem I encountered is that not all pages have 'nextPageToken' value (WHY?) therefore it won't let me get all videos.

Here's my node file:

```
const request = require('request')
var tokens = [];

function getTokens(token) {
   var additions = "";
   if(token != "") additions = '&pageToken='+token;

   request('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=30&type=playlist&channelId=CHANNEL-ID&key=MY-KEY' + additions, function (error, response, body) {
      body = JSON.parse(body)
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body.nextPageToken+"-"+body.items.length);
          getTokens(body.nextPageToken);
        }
   })
};
getTokens("");
```

OUTPUT RESULT: (there should be 800 total results, 30 results per page -> 26 tokens) as you can see, only 15 tokens are available:

[image: List of tokens]

Comment: What are the value of CHANNEL-ID and MY-KEY in url?

Comment: id of YT channel (for example: UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ) and my YouTube API Key

Comment: I found the solution here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36723357/9864141]