# YouTube v3 no longer returning paginated results past 100 records

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

When calling https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?, I can get the first 50 results and subsequent 50 using the nextPageToken; however, when I try to get results past 100, the api returns a 200, gives me total request figure and returns a list - but the list is empty - "items": [].

I have been using these calls in a query for more than 18 months. Has there been a recent change to the API that I've missed in the documentation? Last change I see today doesn't address this issue and the next one from the API reference is from Nov 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue when trying to get all the live broadcasts on YouTube Gaming. Everything I read resulted in some complicated explanation of how Google's search engine returns the count and why they limit some queries to 500 or so, but I have absolutely seen some companies tracking the data beyond the first 100. Nothing answered the issue you and I both ran into, but if I find something I'll report back.

Comment: I saw a few murmurs about reducing the number of records in your query by specifying the publishedAfter/Before parameters.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719895/strange-behaviour-youtube-v3-api/36723357#36723357

Comment: Looks like this may be my only option to pulling back all 282 videos on the channel. Unfortunately, even videos back to 2014 still receive periodic bumps in views we want to track and be aware of it looks like I'll be rewriting my query with the publishedAfter/Before parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "500 results" limit has been silently reduced to 100-150, by design, or by bug.

Either use date ranges, or sub-divide your queries (a and b1, a and b2, a and b3, ....) to keep each result set below 50